# EmberJs: component template

Tags: ember.js

I try to wrap a colorPicker component from http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-colorpicker/
I need to fill the "background-color css attribute" of the template with the "value" attribute of the view...
I have tried to set {{value}} but it does not work...

Any advice ?

JavaScript:

```
App.ColorPicker = Em.View.extend({
      classNames: 'input-append color',
      attributeBindings: ['name', 'value'],
      value: '',
      template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="this.value"}}<span class="add-on"><i style="background-color: {{value}}"></i></span>'),
      didInsertElement: function() {
            $('#backgroundColor').colorpicker({format: "rgb"});
      }
    })

;
```

html:

```
{{view App.ColorPicker placeholder="Background color" name="backgroundColor" valueBinding="App.controller" classNames="input-large" id="backgroundColor"}}
```

Comment: Try valueBinding="view.value" instead of "this.value"

Comment: With view.value I have the following result:<i style="background-color: &lt;script id='metamorph-0-start' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;rgb(255, 30, 0)&lt;script id='metamorph-0-end' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;"></i>

Comment: can u post a fiddle or something because it's hard to debug this way !

Comment: my first github :)  https://github.com/fvisticot/colorpicker.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look into the `{{bindAttr}}` helper. There is an old but good post on it [here](http://www.emberist.com/2012/04/06/bind-and-bindattr.html)

Basically, you can't just drop bound values into HTML tags as it then inserts the wrapper script tags and breaks everything.

What you're looking for is:

```
App.ColorPicker = Em.View.extend({
  classNames: 'input-append color',
  attributeBindings: ['name', 'value'],
  value: '',
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="this.value"}}<span class="add-on"><i {{bindAttr style="view.iStyle"}}></i></span>'),
  iStyle: function() {
    return "background-color:" + this.get('value');
  }.property('value'),
  didInsertElement: function() {
    $('#backgroundColor').colorpicker({format: "rgb"});
  }
});
```

Comment: Tx a lot !. Works fine yet. I think the iStyle function should be return "background-color"...

Comment: You are correct, changed, I'm a coffeescript guy so I'm always forgetting to put return when I change back these days